# Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, query, sintaxe

Quero que minha consulta me retorne apenas o primeiro registro da primeira tabela (se caso houver dados nela), pois a segunda tabela não há dados repetidos.

Porém ele me retorna esse erro:

> Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UNION and LIMIT

Meu código:

```
SELECT administradores_id FROM adm LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT usuarios_id FROM user;
```

Comment: Se você quer **apenas o primeiro registro da primeira tabela**, por que fazer o union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(SELECT administradores_id FROM adm LIMIT 1)
UNION
SELECT usuarios_id FROM user;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Union2.sql).

Há uma ambiguidade que o *parser* não consegue resolver sozinho, você tem que ajudar com uma sintaxe menos ambígua.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se esta é uma *query* que dê algum resultado útil, mas não sei detalhes.

Comment: Funcionou aqui. Obrigada.